# localhost is working but not 127.0.0.1 in windows 7

Tags: windows, xampp, localhost

I am running xampp on windows 7. When I do `http://localhost`, I get the xampp welcome screen in my web browser but `http://127.0.0.1` does not work. In my windows hosts file, I have uncommented 127.0.0.1 localhost but the problem still exists. I have checked to see if firewall is blocking anything but still no good results.

How do I resolve this problem.

Comment: did you configure a website on 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two or three shot in the dark guesses.  This is how I would diagnose the issue.

- It's possible that your web browser is resolving `localhost` on your computer to  the IPV6 loopback address, `::1`. Compare the results of typing `http://[::1]` and compare the results to `http://127.0.0.1` and `http://localhost` to see if that reveals anything.  As to why xampp is working on IPV6, but not IPV4 is another issue.
- You **might** have a web proxy installed on your network and your Internet Options or browser settings is configured to use it. This will bypass DNS and the hosts file and send the request straight to the proxy.  And the proxy server probably resolves 127.0.0.1 and localhost differently.   This also applies to any sort of local proxy, internet speed-up software, anti-virus scanner, Fiddler, etc...  Try going to Control Panel->Internet Options and select the Connections tab. Then select the "LAN settings" button. Make sure all the checkboxes are turned off on this dialog.  Run the "Setup" button at the top of the Connections dialog just to be sure.  **See picture below**
- Disable the Windows Firewall and/or any other sort of Firewall software you may have. Just so we can rule that out.  Any change?
- But your BEST option will be to install Wireshark or Netmon and get a trace of `http://localhost` connection and compare that to the `http://127.0.0.1` address.  That should reveal something...

[image]

Answer (score 12):

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```

This should do the work

Comment: wholly crap. U rock. I was able to 127 and 192 on most things (couchpotato, sabnzb, plex) but it would not work on Sonarr. Only localhost would. I add the 127 and my 192 address and they both work now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What I had to do was:

1) Make sure I had all files located inside of `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` backed up somewhere, just in case.

2) Go to the `windows search` OR `control panel` and open`Turn Windows features on or off`

3) The box next to `Internet Information Services` needs to be checked (it will appear as a green square inside of the grey square).

4) Now I can type [127.0.0.1](http://127.0.0.1) or http://localhost and get the correct page which should look like [this image](http://blog.monitis.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/iis7.jpg)

5) `Profit`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that is the solution. IIS is enabled on my computer. But I am not using asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

I personally couldn't get **127.0.0.1** working on it's own in the Apache **httpd.conf** file. So I added a port number at the end. Usually it's just **:80**.

However, I have Skype running on my machine which causes a conflict so I use port **:8080**.

**Listen 127.0.0.1:8080**

Is what I have in the config file and in the browser I enter: 
**http://localhost:8080**

This works and keeps it on local only. You can either type in **localhost** to find your apache server or your local ip address. You can find your local ip address in cmd with an **ipconfig** command.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution taken from [here](https://ao-system.net/en/note/47)

**Increase the priority of IPv4**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies
Querying active state...

Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
        50      0  ::1/128
        40      1  ::/0
        35      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
        30      2  2002::/16
         5      5  2001::/32
         3     13  fc00::/7
         1     11  fec0::/10
         1     12  3ffe::/16
         1      3  ::/96


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 55 4
Ok.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies
Querying active state...

Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------

    55      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
    50      0  ::1/128
    40      1  ::/0
    30      2  2002::/16
     5      5  2001::/32
     3     13  fc00::/7
     1     11  fec0::/10
     1     12  3ffe::/16
     1      3  ::/96
```

Here is the result:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping localhost

Pinging Sumonst21 [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Hope this will help someone coming to this thread by 2022 :)

Answer (score -3):

If **localhost** working and **127.0.0.1** not working

Try **192.168.1.1**  or  **192.168.1.(your system number)**

It should work..